# How to retrive the notebook contents or the url of a particular cell in Google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is there a way to get or compute the URL to a cell in Colab? I know you can click on a link button to get the url, or click on the TOC and get the #scrollTo=J1nFJPC9V1-X part of the URL, but I want a way to generate this.

The use case is I search colabs for headlines, and I want to generate a link that opens a colab to that heading. Suppose I know the id for a colab, and I know it has a heading called "Printing arrays". I want to generate a full link that opens it at that cell.

Is it possible to compute the scrollTo part, or retrieve it somehow?

Comment: i guess there's no perfect way of doing this. but there's one thing i found. the demo code snippets works exactly the way you want. so you can just copy that to your drive and edit it. i know it's not a perfect way. but some way. https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb#scrollTo=GJBs_flRovLc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example snippet that will find the cell ID with particular contents:

```
from google.colab import _message

# Load the notebook JSON.
nb = _message.blocking_request('get_ipynb')

# Search for the markdown cell with the particular contents.
for cell in nb['ipynb']['cells']:
  if (cell['cell_type'] == 'markdown' and 
      '\n'.join(cell['source']).find('## Printing arrays') >= 0):
    print (f'Cell ID for header is #{cell["metadata"]["id"]}')
```

Here's a complete example notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11jOuhB7wzm1d2P85mrmhBWycogJ_9F0q

Comment: It turns out to be even easier if you can read the notebook json file, you can get the id from there. I don't suppose you know if you can get the fileid from this package also?

Comment: In case anyone finds this, there seems to be a solution to getting the current open notebook here: https://github.com/airesearch-in-th/kora/blob/7c4c61992a1566a28168473d5beec6bff95515f0/kora/drive.py#L79

Comment: I can get the answer to work in a new notebook, but when I run it in an existing large notebook (also in Google Drive, with default runtime), it returns `nb = None` without any failure message.

Comment: I changed the answer to use `blocking_request('get_ipynb', timeout_sec=20)` and this works!

Comment: How on earth did you figure out this hidden feature? You don't happen to work for the Colab team, do you?